# How to resize Text field in IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, textfield

I'm able to resize Text Field in Chrome & other browsers. However, I'm not able to make the same work in IE9, even after installing the Chrome frame for IE. I use for Ex:
style="resize:horizontal;"

Ex:

Can someone suggest me how to make it work in IE browsers?
Thanks.

****EDIT****

Ok, So after a lot of tweaking around, I finally made it to work for IE9 !! Yay :)

First things first : You need to install the Chrome Frame on IE9.

Then you add some tags for it to render on IE.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

Here's the complete code :

```
<!DOCTYPE >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=IE9">
<!-- X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1-->

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

<head>
    <title>Text Feilds</title>

   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt1" style= "resize: horizontal"; />
<input type="text" id="txt2" style= "resize: both"; />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make your edit appear stand out clearly by placing a bold *EDIT* word or something else meaningful. It's difficult for a person who looks at your question for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp you will see that this feature is not supported in IE at all.

If you want to support this feature in all browsers you will have to create your own resize function in javascript (our use any framework if there is one).

Comment: I know that it's not supported in IE at all. But, is there a way by which I could?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It still does not work in IE. Appreciate your help :) Cheers

Comment: Realy does not work on older versions than IE9 and other browsers... woudl have to spent more time in it. Sorry. (removed code because of missleading content)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t, in any simple way. According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize there is no support in IE 9, and IE 10 status is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

That's HTML5 markup and older versions of IE do not support HTML5 or HTML5 ready. IE 9 only supports it in parts