# How to resize a text field in Chrome?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, dom

I need to resize a text field in google Chrome. I want to be able to drag the end of the textfield horizontally & vertically.

This is what I have tried so far. I'm able to see the resize icon at the corner of the text field, but not able to move it either ways. I have used `style="resize:horizontal;"` Could some tell me where I am going wrong... 
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Text Feilds</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       </script>
 </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="resize:horizontal;" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" style="resize:both;" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" style="resize:vertical;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the specifications, you could make any element (including an `<input type=text>` element) resizeable by setting the `overflow` property to any value other than `visible`, in addition to setting the `resize` property.

In practice, even browsers that support the `resize` property at all may have restrictions in its applicability. Chrome does not make an `<input type=text>` element resizeable if you do the above. This is probably a bug, since it is clearly trying to do that: a resize handle appears. Safari, on the other hand, makes it resizeable even if you just set `resize`, without setting `overflow`.

There’s a workaround that seems to work on Chrome, though it’s kludgy and not robust-looking. Put the `input` element inside a `div`, and make the `div` resizeable and set the `input` width near 100%. Not quite 100%, since this would mess things up (no room for the resize handle). Something like this:

```
<div style="resize: horizontal; width: 15em; 
            overflow: auto; border: solid gray 1px">
  <input style="width: 96%; border: none; resize: none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a textarea element instead.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/AAWwa/)

Comment: I would think that the input tag would at least allow resizing horizontally.

Comment: @Mythril : Thanks. But, I want it to happen to a Text Field.            Tyler : Yes, AFAIK it should happen horizontally, I mean atleast in HTML5 format . Thanks

Comment: TextArea by default can be resized. How about for a Text field?

Comment: A text area is a text field. If you mean <input type="text">, it is not specified to work that way. See mtk's answer.

Comment: Yes, I mean <input type="text">. Is there a way by which I could?

Answer (score 0):

`resize` is a not style property of html input type `text`. So, that means you are trying to assign a wrong attibute to the text input tag.

Check this [link](http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/resize.htm) for more details. From the link

> Applies To
>   elements with 'overflow' other than visible

Use `textarea` as explaind in other answer.

Comment: This guy, seems to have done it. .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535439/how-to-resize-text-field-in-ie9?rq=1